# How can I create a realistic stack of pages?

Tags: mesh, texturing, extrude

I'm really new to blender and one thing that I'm finding difficult is how to create pages on a notepad so when it is viewed from the side you can clearly see pages and image bleed (see picture in link).

I tried duplicating the plane 50 times but it didn't look good so I chose to extrude the plane to the final height of the notepad but now I can't figure out a way to split the sides so they look like they are pages.

This is what I want it to look like (more images [here](http://www.kikki-k.com/adhesive-notepad-cute-2016)):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm struggling to find a way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55372/how-to-model-spread-book-interior/55404#55404

Answer (score 1):

You can uv unwrap your volume/pad from the top with project from view, so that you will have the yellow colors bleeding along the sides as in your reference, as long as you keep the UV inside the texture. Then you can use a normal input combined to a dot node to separate the vertical sides and the top face and use this output to create a variation of the texture (adding some vertically compressed noise for page division, multiplied to the image texture and a bit desaturated). This texture is then plugged into a basic diff+glossy mixed shader. Big advantages here, you are sure the colors on the side are in good position regards to the top, and you can change the whole thing by tuning the uv or changing the texture !

[image: It's always better with a drawing]

Blend is [here](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/84782)

Comment: Improved the answer, and I think the question is not really a duplicate as it has been marked, as the answers in the duplicate question are not taking into account the bleeding of the colors on the sides of the stack of pages, which seem problematic for the poster.