# How to model a curved book page?

Tags: modeling

I am a noob in blender. I want to create this non-symmetrical curve between the top curve of the page and the bottom curve of the page, but I couldn't find the way to make it.

Is there anyone want to tell me how to make it, or give me some easy tips and a tutorial?

[image]

Comment: Do you need to animate it?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55372/how-to-model-spread-book-interior

Comment: @RobinBetts no.. i just want to modeling a book for a mockup..

Answer (score 8):

Quite nice result with **Cloth Sim** + **Empty**

[image]

Under *Physics Properties* Enable *Cloth Simulation, Preset* > **Rubber > Vertex Mass decrease to 0.3 kg**
Create two *Vertex Groups*, one for *Pinning* second to *Hook* *Empty*

- **Pinning** - select left two line of vertices + right-down vertex, add a new group and assign. Select second line of vertices and lower weight to 0.5

[image]

- **Hook** - for this vertex group select only right-down vertex, add a new vertex group and assign

[image]

*Snap cursor to Selected* (Shift+S), go to object mode and add *Empty*.
Select page and add **Hook modifier** above *Cloth* with *Object > Empty*, *Vertex Group > Hook*. As a last moodier add *Subdivision* (with border vertices selected press Shift+E+1 (Crease) to keep sharp edge shapes of page.

[image]

[image]

---

**Tip**: to affect curvature at book binding slide second edge more left or right or add one more edge loop ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: 'Quite' nice?  That's 'quite' an understatement .. :D ..And 'quite' nicely presented, too .. !

Comment: @RobinBetts Ehm ... thanks :) "Quite" I mean - sometimes it lives by its life. You know cloth :) I didn't test it such deeply, so there can be a case ...

Comment: It's a great answer.:)

Comment: Effectively a really great answer (missed it before today). Thanks!

Comment: I'm having difficulty implementing this in Blender 3. The cloth wrinkles and stretches when animated. Does anyone have any updated suggestions on how to achieve this effect?

Comment: @Craig -Seems to be working fine in 3.x ... if you want more advice please create new Question with screen of your issue and share your simplified file https://blend-exchange.com to let us see your setup. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

'Bendy Bones' are a good fit for this.

Start with a suitably sub-divided plane :

[image: plane]

Create an armature (single bone) and position it along one edge :

[image: armature]

In Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) duplicate the bone and position on the opposite edge :

[image: two bones]

Change the armature Display to 'B-Bone' :

[image: b-bone]

While still in Edit mode, select each bone in turn and change the Bone properties Bendy Bone Segments to a suitably high number for your mesh level of detail (eg, 10 - more segments make for a smoother bend) :

[image: segments]

Now swap back to Object mode and parent the armature to the plane (select the plane, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select the armature, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, Armature Deform with Automatic Weights).

Now, bending the bone (by changing the Curve XY Offsets) will bend the page.

[image: bent bones]

[image: final]