# Unfold / peel off animation

Tags: animation, workflow

I have to create a similar animation with the attached image.

How to create  this effect in Blender?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192079/2214

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54114/how-to-make-peeling-edges-of-a-paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Plane deformed by **Curve modifier** plus **Mirror modifier**

[image]

It is quite tricky to work with curve for me. But in this case just add *Curve*, switch type to *2D* (under *Curve Properties*), rotate *90*°on *X*, in edit mode shape curve as you need. In object mode rotate on *Z* axis to let curve peel from cornet. Before you add paper a Curve modifier move curve object origin to paper's left top corner. Animate curve's *Location*.

[image]

[image]