# Bake an Object Animation.Deformed by Modifier

Tags: animation, lattice

I have an animated lattice that I'm using to deform a page animation, and I'm wondering if I can bake the deforms to the mesh somehow. The Bake Animation operation ignores the lattice and applying the lattice as a shape key only works one frame at a time.

[image: Deform example]
[image: Deform example]

Comment: Try export as Alembic and Import back ... also there are other options how to animate page if you are interested https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192079/2214

Answer (score 3):

Baked can be only object transforms (loc/rot/scale) or any parametr, but not vertex (as shape keys that provides linear transformation from loc to loc). For such thing you would have to use some format that supports *Mesh Sequence* like Alembic (.abc)

- Just select your object go to Export > Alembic.
- Import > Alembic - imported object gets automatically assigned **Mesh Sequence Cache** modifier were you can tweak few parameters

[image]

[image]
Note: I cant pack .abc into blend so just delete my object *Plane.abc* and Export-Import again.