# Transform a semi-sphere into a rounded rectangle

Tags: animation, mesh, transforms

I'm new to Blender and I'm struggling to find the way to transform (by an animation shoude be better) a semi-sphere object to a rounded rectangle.

Please look at the image posted where the red semi-sphere:
[image]

is transformed into a red rounded rectanlge: [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried shapekeys?

Comment: no, I wasn't aware of that--I'm still at a basic level of using Blender...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *Cast* modifier on a rounded cuboid should do that for you..

[image]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut the default cube in half, <kbd>V</kbd> cut the loop
- <kbd>X</kbd> delete the bottom half, <kbd>F</kbd> fill the hole
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> etc. scale to shape in Edit Mode, top edges only, if your reference indicates..
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut in loops to even up density.

Add a *Cast* modifier:

[image]

- Factor `0` is the original, and `1` is the hemisphere.

This one's followed up with a level of *Subdivision Surface*.

In the example, I've adjusted the topology of the bottom surface to suit a bit better, and added a Smooth modifier aimed at the bottom surface only, to make the result a bit more reasonable after deformation, bevelling and subdiv. .. but that's optional. You could take that further, or not do it at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please can you elaborate better the steps you made to get the result? Unfortunately I'm not be able to reproduce your result. I'm not be able to get a sphere: I get a distroced cuboid...

Comment: The sphere is centred on the object origin, (adjust with Header > Object >Set Origin). The scaling to make a cuboid must be in Edit Mode. (If you scale in Object mode, the sphere-effect will scale along with the object) Will try to fill in some steps for you.

Comment: @xdevel2000 see edit.. hope it helps..

Comment: Amazing, now it works... however now I've another problem: if I make the animations inserting two keyframes at 0 (factor 1) and at 40 (factor 0) and then I apply the modifer the animation is lost... any help also on this?

Comment: The animation is _in_  the modifier. Applying it will store the mesh at the point of application. If you need to lose the modifier (say, for export) then you could bake its effect, frame-by-frame ... see e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230703/35559 search 'Blender Bake Modifier' or somesuch. If you have a particular version of the question not previously covered, then go ahead and post.. we'll do our best :)

Comment: I'll try to make a new post to explain better my problem